# Jquery getting input data?

Tags: jquery, image

I have an upload button, when I upload an image it previews the image below. 
I would like to get the value of the image and store it in a var. ('example.png').
This needs to change if a new file is uploaded.

Extra: Is there anyway I can upload more than one image ? If I wanted to upload a max of 4?

```js
var loadFile = function (event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- File name - Image -->
<input name="image-upload" id="image-upload" type="file" accept="image/*"            onchange="loadFile(event)">
<br>
<br>
<img id="output"/>
```

Comment: For uploading mulitple images you can set **multiple** attribute to true and **size** attribute to **4**. for e.g. ```<input type="file" id="picture" size="10" multiple="true" name="attachments[]" />```

Comment: You already have the image name as you're displaying it. Do you want to store the image name with or without the file path?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to store the image name with a path, in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store the filename in a variable calling this function:

```
var storeFileName = function () {
    var files = [];
    var upload = document.getElementById("image-upload");

    upload.onchange = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < upload.files.length; i++) {
            files.push(upload.files[i].fileName);
        }
    }
}
```